# Set values for empty list within nested dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion

I have a cte query that returns me results of values that are linked (i.e. child -> parent).

Then in Python I am trying to create a nested dictionary that would represent something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Child_example",
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "child_parent_1",
            "parents": [{"name": "child_parent_1_parent", "parents": [{"name": "end", "parents": []}]}]
        },
        {
            "name": "child_parent_2",
            "parents": [{"name": "end", "parents": []}]
        },
        {
            "name": "child_parent_3",
            "parents": [{"name": "child_parent_3_parent", "parents": [{"name": "end", "parents": []}]}]
        }
    ]
}
```

My input data looks something like so (it can have more data):

| child_col | parent_col | name | depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Child_example | child_parent_1_col | child_parent_1 | 0 |
| Child_example | child_parent_2_col | child_parent_2 | 0 |
| Child_example | child_parent_3_col | child_parent_3 | 0 |
| child_parent_1_col | child_parent_1_parent | 1_parent | 1 |
| child_parent_2_col | end | 1_parent | 1 |
| child_parent_3_col | child_parent_3_parent | 3_parent | 1 |
| child_parent_3_parent | end | end_3 | 2 |
| child_parent_1_parent | end | end_1 | 2 |

However with my code so far:

```
        r_dict = defaultdict(list)
        depth_zero = [x for x in rows if x.depth == 0]
        for row in depth_zero:
            r_dict['name'] = row.path_key
            r_dict['parents'].append({'name': row.path_parent_key, 'parents': []})
        depth_not_zero = [x for x in rows if x.depth != 0]
        #  Set inner levels
        for parent in r_dict['parents']:
            name = parent['name']
            inner_parent = parent['parents'].copy()
            for row in depth_not_zero:
                if row.path_key == name:
                    inner_parent.append({'name': row.path_parent_key, 'parents': []})
                    name = row.path_parent_key
            parent['parents'] = inner_parent
```

I only manage to achieve to append it to initial "parents", instead of setting the ultimate nested "parents". I know it is to do with this line of code:

```
inner_parent.append({'name': row.path_parent_key, 'parents': []})
```

But I cannot work out how to essentially get and set it. Would this be a case for recursion instead of the way I am doing it?

Below is an example of the first nested dictionary output that I am currently creating with my code:

```
{
    "name": "Child_example",
    "parents": [
        {
            "name": "child_parent_1",
            "parents": [
                {"name": "child_parent_1", "parents": []}, {"name": "end", "parents": []}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input, either as it is stored in your database or when you read it from the db to Python?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Have added example data in table.

Comment: What is `depth`? Another column in your CTE?

Comment: @gimix Yes, sorry forgot to add that I have just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit baffled by the way you are assigning the "name" value: "Child_example" comes from `child_col`, "child_parent_1" from `name`, "child_parent_3_parent" from `parent_col`. So I simplified it a bit: I put in the second column of the child row the same value as in the first column of its parents rows. That said, if you really need to take the names from  different columns it's just a matter of adding some `if`s.

My proposal is to loop over the rows in reverse order, creating the inner dicts and then moving them into the outer ones:

```
rows = [["c1","p1c1",0],
        ["c1","p2c1",0],
        ["c1","p3c1",0],
        ["p1c1","p1p1c1",1],
        ["p2c1","end",1],
        ["p3c1","p1p3c1",1],
        ["p1p3c1","end",2],
        ["p1p1c1","end",2]]

r_dict = {}
for row in reversed(rows):
    if row[1] == "end":
        r_dict[row[0]] = {"name":row[0], "parents":[]}
    else:
        if not row[0] in r_dict:
            r_dict[row[0]] = {"name":row[0], "parents":[]}
        r_dict[row[0]]["parents"].append(r_dict[row[1]])
        del r_dict[row[1]]
        
r_dict
{'c1': {'name': 'c1', 'parents': [{'name': 'p3c1', 'parents': [{'name': 'p1p3c1', 'parents': []}]}, {'name': 'p2c1', 'parents': []}, {'name': 'p1c1', 'parents': [{'name': 'p1p1c1', 'parents': []}]}]}}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, had to focus on something else, this helped immensely I had to tweak it a bit, to remove duplicates but it worked great!